# Issue calling VB .NET WebMethod using jQuery

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, vb.net

I'm calling a WebMethod from jQuery, but it does not seem to execute the success or failure Methods, nor return an error.  This is despite me stripping it down to absolute basics.

This is the first time I'm doing it, so I must be missing something.

This is my WebMethod

```
<ServiceContract(Namespace:="")>

<AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode:=
AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)>
Public Class Timebox

<OperationContract()>
Public Shared Function CreateNew() As String

  Return "testing"

End Function

End Class
```

and this is the jQuery call

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/App_Code/Timebox.vb/CreateNew",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
      var results = (response.d);
      alert(results)
    },
    failure: function(response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
});
```

Comment: Is that URL correct?

Comment: As he's saying, `url:` should be in form of Timebox.aspx/CreateNew.  I don't think it's hitting your URL.  Also, recommend to make this a web application as nothing should reference a ".vb" file.

Comment: Web methods are prefaced by `<WebMethod()> _`, no?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions.  I eventually managed to get this to work by using the ASP. Net AJAX Framework way of calling Web services using ScriptManager