# Can't browse to web service in App_Code folder

Tags: vb.net, web-services, url, iis

I'm using FullCalendar in my project, and would like to pull Event objects from a web service written in VB .Net. My web service code sits in the /App_Code/ folder.   Fullcalendar doesn't pull the events, and the message I get in browser console when I debug is:

```
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).  
(XHR)GET - http://localhost:64805/App_Code/TestService.vb/GetEventList?start=2018-02-25&end=2018-04-08&timezone=America%2FChicago&_=1520881721489
```

The problem is that the path is correct, so I'm not sure why fullcalendar can't see it.

If I plug that URL into my browser, I get an error
 HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

The Javascript code to initialise fullcalendar is as follows:

```
var initializeCalendar = function () {
  $('.calendar').fullCalendar({
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events: "../../App_Code/TestService.vb/GetEventList",
    defaultTimedEventDuration: '00:30:00',
    forceEventDuration: true,
    eventBackgroundColor: '#337ab7',
    //editable: false,
    height: screen.height - 160,
    timezone: 'America/Chicago',
    eventStartEditable: false,
    eventDurationEditable: false

  });
};
```

Comment: This is a lot like your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49135985/issue-calling-vb-net-webmethod-using-jquery

Comment: Why it needs to access that path? Neither App_Code folder nor .vb extension should be exposed.

Comment: This is a little different to my previous post.   Previously I was unable to call a Web service from within my Javascript code.   My problem here is that I'm unable to call a Web service from the events argument of the Fullcalendar object

Comment: According to ASP. Net AJAX Framework, Web services sit in the App_code folder as. vb files

Comment: My humble apologies - I should be calling the . svc file,  not the . vb file